# Modal Window effect with CSS

Tags: css, modal-dialog

Well, what I want to do is to create something similar to a modal window with CSS. I'm creating something fancy for when a user has JS deactivated, so I can show it with noscript tag.

I have something like this:

```
<div id="ns-overlay">
        <section>
            <h1>¿Some title?</h1>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>
                Content
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#ns-overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    background-image: url('../imgs/ns-overlay.png');
    padding-top: 95px;
}

#ns-overlay section{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.9);
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#ns-overlay section h1,
#ns-overlay section h3,
#ns-overlay section p{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #126D4F;
    /*background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgb(11, 104, 73) 0%, rgb(11, 78, 130) 100%);*/
    margin: 5px;
}

#ns-overlay section h1{
    width: 560px;
    background: #126D4F;
}

#ns-overlay section h3{
    width: 510px;
    background: #0B4F82;
}

#ns-overlay section p{
    background: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5GgL8/2/)

What I actually want to to is to make the overlay disappear when the user click on it.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve the desired effect using the :target pseudo element.  Change the div to an anchor and reference the ID:

```
<a href="#ns-overlay" id="ns-overlay">
  <section>
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <h3>subtitle.</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
  </section>
</a>
```

Then set #ns-overlay to display:none on target:

```
#ns-overlay:target {
  display:none;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5GgL8/9/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you intend to do, my answer is that the css does not work with this type of event. To work with the click event you need to use javascript.